# Help with deriving an existential rule in predicate calculus

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let us work in Von-Neumann-Bernays-Gödel set theory. We abbreviate, $M(X)$ for $(\exists Y)(X\in Y)$, i.e. $X$ is a set, and lower case letters, $x$ stand for $M(X)$. I am having trouble shwing this plainly evident fact that:

$\vdash X\in Y\Rightarrow M(X)$

I am not sure how to proceed, do I just give a normal argument like any other proof or is a formal deduction required using just the axioms and inference rules (Gen and modes ponens of predicate calculus. I f so I am stuck as I am not sure how to derive an existential rule to use here. so if $\mathcal{A}$ is a wff when can I infer $\exists x \mathcal{A}$

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use [Existential Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#Rules_of_Inference) : $x \in Y \to (\exists y)(x \in y)$.

Comment: The "law" can be either a primitive rule, like in Natural Deduction, or an axiom schema or a theroem derived by quantifiers axioms, like in Hilbert-style proof systems.

Comment: $\vdash$ means it is a formal deduction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an existential introduction $\exists x \mathcal{A}(x)$ on a formula $\mathcal{A}(t)$ if $t$ can be freely substituted for $x$ in $\mathcal{A}$, that is, if the substitution doesn't accidentally bind anything that was supposed to be free in $\mathcal{A}$, except for the new binding with the existential quantifier itself.

We can formulate "$M(X)$ stands for $(\exists Y)(X \in Y)$" as the formula "$M(X) \leftrightarrow (\exists Y)(X \in Y)$", where $\leftrightarrow$ is biimplication. If we don't want to assume $\leftrightarrow$ as a symbol of the language and want to work exclusively with $\to$ instead, we can also assume $M(X) \to (\exists Y)(X \in Y)$ and $(\exists Y)(X \in Y) \to M(x)$ as two separate axioms.

Now depending on which system exactly you're working with (a linear sequent system with some axioms and modus ponens and quantifier rules as the only inference rules I assume?), a formal derivation can be given as follows:

1. $\vdash (\exists Y)(X \in Y) \to M(X)\quad $ (axiom)
2. $X \in Y \vdash X \in Y \quad$ (assumption)
3. $X \in Y \vdash (\exists Y)(X \in Y) \quad$ (existential introduction on 2)
4. $X \in Y \vdash M(X)\quad$ (modus ponens on 1,3)
5. $\vdash X \in Y \to M(X) \quad$ (deduction theorem on 2-4)

$Y$ is freely substitutable for $Y$ in $X \in Y$ (there is not anything else that binds it), so we are allowed to do the existential introduction on line 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am still not sure about some points and hope you can elucidate further. Firstly with regards to the existential introduction, are you taking it as an additional inference rule or must we derive it? If we have to derive it, is the following derivation correct:

Comment: Using the following axiom :($\forall x)A(x)\rightarrow A(t)$ ($t$ free for $x$ in $A$), we have $(\forall x)\neg A(x)\rightarrow \neg A(t)$. Then using the tautology $(p\rightarrow\neg q)\rightarrow (q\rightarrow\neg p)$ we have $((\forall x)\neg A(x)\rightarrow \neg A(t))\rightarrow (A(t)\rightarrow\neg(\forall x) \neg A(x))$ and by MP we infer $A(t)\rightarrow\neg(\forall x) \neg A(x)$, i.e. $A(t)\rightarrow (\exists x) A(x)$ as $(\exists x)A(x)\leftrightarrow\neg(\forall x) \neg A(x)$. And as $x$ is free for $x$ we have, $\vdash A(x)\rightarrow (\exists x) A(x)$.

Comment: Secondly I am a bit confused about you comments on the biconditional, as the language just consists of the conditional connective $\rightarrow$, so why can't we just define the biconditional as the conjunction of the conditional statement and its converse just as we only have one quantifier in the language and define the other one in terms of the other.  In the same vein why do you say we need to introduce the definition of a set ($M(X)$) as an axiom instead of just a definition? Thanks again.

Comment: Which rules and connectives are available as primitives and which ones have to be derived entirely depends on the system you're working in. Some languages have $\leftrightarrow$ as an elementary part of the language and some calculi have an $\exists I$ rule, others may not. You'd need to tell me which particular rule system you're working in to answer that question.

Comment: Ad $\leftrightarrow$: If you don't want $\leftrightarrow$ as part of your alphabet, yes, you can define it in terms of $\to$, like I did. Either you stipulate two different axioms, one for each direction, or you write it as one axiom with the two directions conjoined, $(M(X) \to (\exists Y)(X \in Y)) \land ((\exists Y)(X \in Y) \to M(X))$, the use the axioms $(\phi \to \phi) \to \phi$ and $(\phi \to \psi) \to \psi$ to extract the individual conditionals.

Comment: Def. vs. axiom: What would a definition as opposed to an axiom be in such a system of rules? Sure, you can just have it as a background assumption, but you somehow need to have the conditional formula present in your derivation of you want to apply modus ponens on it.

Comment: Deriv. of $\exists E$:  your derivation is missing a few steps (e.g. how to get from $(\forall x) (A(x) \to A(t))$ to $(\forall x) \neg A(x) \to \neg A(t))$ -- that's not a simple application of one rule), but the idea looks fine. In any case, such an axiom does require the specification that the axiom may only be used under the described variable condition, otherwise one gets unsound results.

Comment: Could you please you help me fill in the details and correct my errors? In this predicate calculus we have $(\forall x_i)B(x_i)\rightarrow B(t)$, where $B(x_i)$ is a wff and $t$ is a term free for $x_i$ in $B(x_i)$, as a logical axiom. So I thought I could just use this axiom with the wff $\neg A(x)$ and any term $t$ of the language which is free for $x$ in $A(x)$, to get $(\forall x)\neg A(x)\rightarrow \neg A(t)$. Is this ok?  If not what is missing/incorrect. Thanks again I really appreciate your feedback.